# Is it possible to get a http header set by the website inside of an alert box?

Tags: javascript, java, header, alert, box

I'm new to javascript and i'd like to know if it's possible to make appear the value of a custom header inside of an alert box. For example if i set a custom http header named 'test' with value '123' is it possible to make an alert box with '123' as content?

I'm not looking for a simple alert(123) code but something like

**alert(custom.header.value)**

but i don't know if it's possible since i'm new to javascript. Could you please also let me know a sample valid code? Thanks.

Comment: The header i need to insert inside of an alert box is sent in client request and it's not in the response

Comment: Do you have access to the custom header since you are making the request from the client?

Comment: @CodyS, Yes i have access to the custom header.

Comment: Can you put the custom header into a variable (var header = "123") and then use the alert from there? Or are you trying to get the header from some global variable set by the browser?

Comment: @CodyS This. Or are you trying to get the header from some global variable set by the browser?

Comment: I'm trying to get the header from the browser

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: @CodyS, They are all talking about response headers while i'd like to get request headers.